# Why does this loop only work when I run each iteration manually in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to use a loop to run a function through several species and traits and save their outputs in a df. Since I have to run through several species and through several traits, I tried a nested approach. Sadly, the only output I get after the loop is the iteration for the last species.

The curious thing is that if I just follow each iteration manually (a.k.a. I run i=1, i=2, i=3...) and then the entire code each time, I get the output I want.

I recreated the scenario here with the iris dataset and base functions.
I'm using R 4.0.3

```
#Create the dataframe with each header
out<-data.frame(
    Species=character(),
    Trait=character(),
    Mean=numeric(),
    Median=numeric(),
    St.dev=numeric(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Loop to collect measures for each species and each trait
for (i in length(unique(iris$Species))) {
    Spec<-as.character(unique(iris$Species)[i])
    sbset<-subset(iris, iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i])
        for (j in 1:4) {
            PFT<-names(sbset)[j]
            measures<-sbset[which(sbset[,j] != "NA"), j]
            out[nrow(out)+1,]=list(
                Spec,
                PFT,
                mean(measures),
                median(measures),
                sd(measures))
    }
}

#Check the output
out
```

So, what happens when you just run the loop and check the output is that you only get the Virginica 4 rows, while if you instead try:

```
#Create the dataframe with each header
out<-data.frame(
    Species=character(),
    Trait=character(),
    Mean=numeric(),
    Median=numeric(),
    St.dev=numeric(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Manually loop to collect measures for each species and each trait
#for (i in length(unique(iris$Species))) {

i=1

    Spec<-as.character(unique(iris$Species)[i])
    sbset<-subset(iris, iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i])
        for (j in 1:4) {
            PFT<-names(sbset)[j]
            measures<-sbset[which(sbset[,j] != "NA"), j]
            out[nrow(out)+1,]=list(
                Spec,
                PFT,
                mean(measures),
                median(measures),
                sd(measures))
    }

#}

i=2

    Spec<-as.character(unique(iris$Species)[i])
    sbset<-subset(iris, iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i])
        for (j in 1:4) {
            PFT<-names(sbset)[j]
            measures<-sbset[which(sbset[,j] != "NA"), j]
            out[nrow(out)+1,]=list(
                Spec,
                PFT,
                mean(measures),
                median(measures),
                sd(measures))
    }

i=3

    Spec<-as.character(unique(iris$Species)[i])
    sbset<-subset(iris, iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i])
        for (j in 1:4) {
            PFT<-names(sbset)[j]
            measures<-sbset[which(sbset[,j] != "NA"), j]
            out[nrow(out)+1,]=list(
                Spec,
                PFT,
                mean(measures),
                median(measures),
                sd(measures))
    }


#Check the output
out
```

then you'll get the full list with 12 rows as I intended it to be.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here, and what I misunderstood about nested for loops?

A fun thing I also tried was adding another dataframe to collect each iteration with rbind, but that went even worse: when I try it I get a dataframe with 10 rows and repeated columns in a seemingly random pattern.

This is the code that breaks things more:

```
#Create the dataframe with each header
out<-data.frame(
    Species=character(),
    Trait=character(),
    Mean=numeric(),
    Median=numeric(),
    St.dev=numeric(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

out.file<-data.frame()

#further break things
for (i in length(unique(iris$Species))) {
    Spec<-as.character(unique(iris$Species)[i])
    sbset<-subset(iris, iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i])
        for (j in 1:4) {
            PFT<-names(sbset)[j]
            measures<-sbset[which(sbset[,j] != "NA"), j]
            out[nrow(out)+1,]=list(
                Spec,
                PFT,
                mean(measures),
                median(measures),
                sd(measures))
            out.file<-rbind(out.file,out)
    }
}
out.file
```

Comment: `for (i in length(unique(iris$Species)))`   ->  `for (i in 1:length(unique(iris$Species)))`

Comment: It could be a lazy evaluation problem. `for` loops are lazy. The `apply` family of functions isn’t. What happens if you convert to `lapply`?

Comment: That's it! Thank you Paul, you're right! It was not really looping after all. Cheers!